# Tailwind CSS - Issue with changing margin position on image

Tags: tailwind-css

I'm (very) new to Tailwind and have encountered a problem that is driving me crazy. I'm looking to place an image in a footer. At desktop size (1024px), the image needs to sit to the left of the footer content and then on smaller screens, the logo needs to be centered, pretty standard stuff. As with non-tailwind css, I'm using margin to control this and as guided in the documentation, my default setup is in mobile-first so the horizontal margin is set to auto with the following to put the image in the middle with the aim for it to be set to the left when being viewed at a bigger resolution:

```
<img alt="..." :src="logo" class="mx-auto"/>
```

The key thing here is **mx-auto** which centers the image. As per the documentation, I then want to remove the auto-positioning so I add the following to adjust the margin once the screen is at a bigger resolution.

```
<img alt="..." :src="logo" class="mx-auto lg:mx-0"/>
```

However, when I run this the image just stays positioned in the center of the element when at full desktop resolution. I've tried using **ml-0** just in case there was a problem overriding the original setting but in the inspector, the media query doesn't even attempt to override.

I'm building from a template that does similar things to what I want elsewhere in the project however when I copy that code over, it works until I make a change to the setting (changing a -16 to a -20 etc...) which is also odd. I'm not sure if I've messed something up with my configuration or am just missing something basic but any pointers would be really appreciated.

Just in case its something to do with the container the image is in, here's the wider container:

```
<div class="container mx-auto px-4">
   <div class="flex flex-wrap text-center lg:text-left">
      <div class="w-full lg:w-6/12 px-4">
        <img alt="..." :src="logo" class="max-w-250-px pb-4 mx-auto lg:mx-0"/>
      </div>
   </div>
</div>
```

Maybe something to do with the flex?

Comment: It seems it works correctly. check this https://play.tailwindcss.com/lVbv9gxkoB

Comment: That's very odd. Thank you for checking. I'm still confused as to why it's not working like this on my local deployment. Do you know of anything in Tailwinds configuration that can affect media queries?

As mentioned in my og post, I saw some odd behavior with the template's other queries where if I changed their values just by m-16 to m-20 the query itself seemed to break and not register the desired change at different resolutions.

Answer (score 1):

1. It is max-w-[250px] not max-w-250-px
2. Why not use the flex container you already have to get it done?

What you want is this: https://play.tailwindcss.com/wgHwT7KMJ5